# Start using Worklight without modifying mobile app

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst, mobile-application

Current mobile app uses REST web-services for data exchange and registration for push notifications using 3rd-party backend. Is it possible to use Worklight backend instead of 3rd-party backend? The requirement is not to change current mobile app.

Comment: If you want to use Worklight's backend, you need to use Worklight's APIs... in the client-side...

Answer (score 0):

To use push notifications in Worklight, you need to use the Worklight client-side and server-side APIs. You cannot achieve this without touching the client-side of your project.